# How to stop newline chars from escaping OLD gnu sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace a line in a file with multiple lines. When I had only one new line char ( \'$'\n ). it worked fine, however when I use two of them, it escapes my sed and the file wont run anymore.

```
sed 's/TextImLookingFor/My\'$'\nReplacement\'$'\nText/g' /path/to/File.txt
```

File.txt:

```
This is a file
TextImLookingFor
look at all this text
```

DesiredOutput

```
This is a file
My
Replacement
Text
look at all this text
```

Actual Output

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching ''''
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: You can't escape single quotes inside single quoted strings. That doesn't work. Why are you trying to use `$'\n'` here at all? Does just using `\n` in the replacement not do what you want?

Comment: it worked with the first one+ if i use double quotes for my sed command then it prints out the variable instead of an actual new line

Comment: Does `sed 's/TextImLookingFor/My\nReplacement\nText/'` not work for you?

Comment: all '\n' print out as 'n'

Comment: In a single quoted string? What shell is this? Does using `\\n` work better?

Comment: And you *can* escape a single quote inside a `$''` string (oddly to my mind). So your context in the original command is *very* complicated. Your command is parsed as `sed`, `'s/TextImLookingFor/My\'`, `$'\nReplacement\'$'`, `\nText/g'`, `/path/to/File.txt` which is decidedly not what you intended I don't think (and the cause of the quote error because that last single quote is unmatched).

Comment: GNU bash version 2.04.0(1)-release and '\\n' prints out '\n'

Comment: Whenever you have problems with escaping, you should try to make the command work without escaping first. In this case, you can do this with a sed file. There is no way to escape something if you don't know what exactly you're trying to escape (and bash can automatically escape things for you with `printf %q`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using older BSD sed you can do:

```
sed $'s/TextImLookingFor/My\\\nReplacement\\\nText/' file
This is a file
My
Replacement
Text
look at all this text
```

This should work with newer gnu-sed as well. However newer gnu-sed may just need:

```
sed 's/TextImLookingFor/My\nReplacement\nText/' file
```

Comment: This worked! Thankyou. I didnt see your $sign in your response :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/TextImLookingFor/c\My\nReplacement\nText' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this command

```
sed 's/TextImLookingFor/My\'$'\nReplacement\'$'\nText/g' /path/to/File.txt
```

is that it isn't parsing the way you expect it is.

You **cannot** escape a single quote inside a single quoted string. You **can** escape a single quote inside a `$'...'` quoted string however (I'm not really sure why).

So the above command **does not** parse this way (as you might expect):

```
[sed] [s/TextImLookingFor/My\'$[\nReplacement\'$]\nText/g] [/path/to/File.txt]
```

instead it parses this way:

```
[sed] [s/TextImLookingFor/My\]$[\nReplacement\'$]\nText/g' [/path/to/File.txt]
```

with a mismatched single quote at the end and an unquoted `\nText/g` bit.

That is the cause of your problem.

If you can't just use `\n` in your replacement (your version of `sed` doesn't support that) and you need to use `$'\n'` then you would need to use something like

```
sed 's/TextImLookingFor/My\'$'\nReplacement\\'$'\nText/g' /path/to/File.txt
```